Image processing with YOLOv5
I'm working on an image processing project. I was working with the YOLO model, but the error I got was that the libraries in the requirements.txt file in YOLOv5 are conflicting with each other. Even though I have fixed the errors one by one, when I change the version of a library, many other libraries are affected. Has anyone else encountered this problem before? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.
I also tried with YOLOv3, but I'm getting the same error there too. I'm trying my training on Colab and Kaggle.
